# Async method has return@async even though it highlights it red and says A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')

Tags: android, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

```
class ProductRepository(private val productDao: ProductDao) {
    val searchResults = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>()

    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

 

    fun findProduct(name: String) {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            searchResults.value = asyncFind(name).await()
        }
    }

    private fun asyncFind(name: String): Deferred<List<Product>?> {
        coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            return@async productDao.findProduct(name)
        }
    }
}
```

for some reasons ide requires a return expression in asyncFind method or suggests to get rid of explicitly specified return type just like this

```
private fun asyncFind(name: String) {
        coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            return@async productDao.findProduct(name)
        }
    }
```

in this case i have a toruble with await in findProduct method. why it happens and how should i fix it?

I've tried all the variants suggested by IDE and none of them worked. Replacing return@async with simple return does not work either. Current tutorial i am following does not depict this trouble

Comment: Please share `productDao.findProduct(name)` code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
private fun asyncFind(name: String): Deferred<Result<PeoplePollResponse, Failure>> {
        val result =coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
             return@async productDao.findProduct(name)
        }
        return result
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

function with block body:

```
private fun asyncFind(name: String): Deferred<List<Product>?> {
    return coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        productDao.findProduct(name)
    }
}
```

or

single-expression function

```
private fun asyncFind(name: String): Deferred<List<Product>?> =
    coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        productDao.findProduct(name)
    }
```

---

The pair of braces after `async(Dispatchers.IO)` is a lambda, and takes the last expression as returned value.
The pair of braces after `: Deferred<List<Product>?>` is the block body of a function, and needs the `return` keyword.

---

Except for Java interop, you should not need to use `Deferred` as a return type. If you want to switch the dispatcher, just do [`withContext`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html).

```
private suspend fun find(name: String): List<Product>? =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        productDao.findProduct(name)
    }
```